# how to lower boot up time? (many apps 122, rooted device)

Tags: app-widgets, boot, partitions, link2sd

> **[old subject: link2sd not mounting second partition, "quick restart"**
>   fails too]
>
> [IMPORTANT: boot time took 20 minutes, see at the end...]
>
> My phone suddenly reboot (while I was sleeping), and from that on,
>   link2sd fails to mount the 2nd partition that was working flawlessly
>   for a long time.
>
> Now, everytime I boot, it freezes on black screen, until I unplug the
>   sdcard, then it shakes and continues booting. After plug the sdcard
>   back it seems to create this device: /dev/block/mmcblk1p2 (instead of
>   mmcblk0p2).
>
> After I re-insert the sdcard, link2sd fails to mount again, I recreate
>   the scripts, do a "quick reboot" but it fails again. (I guess it was
>   expecting mmcblk1p2 but sdcard was now back at mmcblk0p2).
>
> I plug the sdcard on pc and the 2nd partition data is there, it is
>   ext3, all seems ok there.
>
> This
>   [Partitioned sdcard not working with link2sd](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24291/partitioned-sdcard-not-working-with-link2sd),
>   does not work for me :(
>
> I changed the script at
>   /data/data/com.buak.Link2SD/files/init-link2sd.sh that was created
>   with mmcblk1p2 to mmcblk0p2. After that, a "quick reboot" wont work
>   despite I got /data/sdext2 mounted (manually with terminal).
>
> A normal reboot sends me back to the black screen, my guess is I have
>   "created a linked app" that may have widget but I dont know which one.
>   I tried a few I remembered but didnt work, still same problem...
>
> I am still fighting with this... I will try more tricks and report
>   later...
>
> Any tips (tricks) ?
>
> EDIT: I used adb logcat (found good tutorial here:
>   http://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/)
>   and the last log message was:
>
> ```
> D/dalvikvm( 1506): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 830K, 37% free 6859K/10759K, external 1429K/1581K, paused 77ms
> ```
>
> After that it froze, I started it again and it brought more log than
>   before...
>
> After 20 minutes, the phone finally completely boot up! thats too much
>   time... now it seems to be working ok... At this point my question
>   changes to "how to lower boot up time?" is it ok to change the
>   subject?

---

***subject: how to lower boot up time?***

So scanPackage took too much time and I am uninstalling not needed packages... I guess it is good to keep the other research info I did so people can come here and understand they just need to wait a long time if they have too many apps installed on a not so fast device.

Comment: Of course it is OK to change the subject if it turns out it doesn't really fit -- I'd say this is such a case. Even more, I'd *suggest* you do so :) As to your problem: if you have another SDCard to play with, it might be worth to try and see if the problem occurs with that as well. Could be some trouble with the card -- not the first I've heard of.

Comment: thx! I have 122 installed apps, 18 are frozen with link2sd, I will uninstall them... the logcat has this line "I/PackageManager( 1506): Time to scan packages: 949.159 seconds" that is 15 minutes only to scan packages!

Comment: btw, another bkp app tells me I have 219 apps installed...

Comment: Time to cleanup. Do you really need that many apps? Are you really using them? Cannot imagine that :)

Comment: I took a look, I use 90% of them, I did remove the biggest ones (mostly games) about 13, and the "Time to scan packages" improved only to 14min, not that good... I am researching on how to fix that packages scanner, most apps are on sdext2 (may be if the scan could happen before it is mounted, but I understand it can be messy, just an idea..), anyway my root is kernel 2.6.35, I am thinking on getting version 4, my guess they may have improved it? anyway why I research on it? if I need the phone on emergency and need to reboot, I need to unplug the sdcard to boot, and will miss most apps...

Comment: Aren't you mixing up kernel version with Android version now? I didn't know that any Android version already came with a kernel version 4.x (AFAIK there is not even such a kernel now). According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history), Jelly Bean (Android 4.1/4.2) ships with kernel 3.0.31. And most likely it's not your root, but your system coming with a kernel ;)

Comment: @AquariusPower: Please ***do not*** put your solution in the body of your question. Please answer your own question with the solution.

Comment: @Izzy android is 2.3.6, kernel 2.6.35.7 :). @ Al Everett I will as soon I can actually improve the boot time lowering it; currently I went from 15min to 14min, so I didnt solve it yet..

Comment: just for info, my boot just took 40 minutes... it seems to scanPackage 2 times them all... that's insane... I think I will give up and try the new android 4 (they released one for galaxy y duos, I just need to find the rooted one)